# BETWEEN query within Cursor not returning all rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a nested cursor statement that is meant to:
1. loop through a 2-column table and and use the first column as the range start and the second column as range end
2. return a 1-column table of all values in a separate table that are within the range (inclusive)

My problem is that the range end value is not being included in the table.

@RangeTable:

```
range1 range2
--------------------
A03    A069
A20    A20
A202   A202
A25    A25
A250   A2509
A251   A251
A2511  A2513
A254   A2549
A263   A2651
------------------
```

The following is the code to create a table containing all Product ID's within the range of all the values. The values are in varchar format. When I query the original table [dbo].[products] using, i.e.
`BETWEEN A03 and A069`
or even a one value range, such as
`BETWEEN 'A25' AND 'A25'`
I get everything I need.

```
Select DISTINCT * into #temp From @RangeTable

DECLARE @prodID varchar(20);
DECLARE @rangestart varchar(20);
DECLARE @rangeend varchar(20);
DECLARE @prods TABLE (ID VARCHAR(32));

DECLARE ranges CURSOR FOR
SELECT RangeFrom, RangeTo FROM #temp

OPEN ranges

FETCH NEXT FROM ranges
INTO @rangestart, @rangeend

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE id CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT c.ID
    FROM dbo.products as c
    WHERE rtrim(ltrim(c.ID)) BETWEEN rtrim(ltrim(@rangestart)) AND rtrim(ltrim(@rangeend))
    ORDER BY c.ID;

    OPEN id
    FETCH NEXT FROM id INTO @prodID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @prods VALUES(@prodID)
        FETCH NEXT FROM id INTO @prodID
    END

    CLOSE id;
    DEALLOCATE id;
    FETCH NEXT FROM ranges INTO @rangestart, @rangeend
END

CLOSE ranges;
DEALLOCATE ranges;
SELECT * FROM @prods
TRUNCATE TABLE #temp
DROP TABLE #temp
```

it does not include the values in range2, and for one value ranges (i.e. 'A20' to 'A20') it skips it entirely.

I have tried using FETCH in other ways, for example setting the CURSOR as SCROLL and using a FETCH LAST, but even this returns the 2nd to last value in the range.

At first I thought it might be a trailing blanks issue, which is why I put in the rtrim and ltrim.
When I debug, I can see that @@FETCH_STATUS changes to -1 following what should be the second to last value in the range.

Thank you in advance for any ideas, hints or suggestions.

Comment: am I correct in assuming that products contains a complete list of the products found in the ranges defined?

Comment: @xQbert yes it does contain a complete list

Comment: ***WHY on earth*** are you using a **cursor** to do a `INSERT INTO .... SELECT ...` query?? That's totally not necessary and pointless.... Cursors are evil, they are **RBAR** (row-by-agonizing-row) processing which is frowned upon heavily in SQL Server ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use a cursor at all?  SQL operates most effectively when processing sets.  As you aren't doing anything special for each row. So, set processing seems like it would be more effective.  Cursors are best used when you MUST process each record individually. For example, you don't know if the data will be of sufficient quality and you must write out records that error to a separate file for processing. (and even that could be done using multiple set based queries...)

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41bf9/1/0

In the example, I simply join the data based on a between ranges and then insert your product id's into a new table "B"

```
SELECT P.ID into B 
FROM products P
INNER JOIN Ranges R
 on P.ID between R.Range1 and R.Range2;
```

Note in my example A250 and A2509 will not include A251

Comment: I am not sure why I decided to make this so complicated. I guess I didn't quite understand how exactly a join worked, I thought each individual row had to match up.

Comment: that's the power of SQL.  It doesn't have to be an exact match, it just must match the criteria for the join.  In this case a  between.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to have all of this?

```
WHERE rtrim(ltrim(c.ID)) BETWEEN rtrim(ltrim(@rangestart)) AND rtrim(ltrim(@rangeend))
```

Why not just?

```
WHERE c.ID BETWEEN @rangestart AND @rangeend
```

And, have you tried:

```
WHERE c.ID >= @rangestart AND c.ID <= @rangeend
```

To get the result you are you are looking for?

Comment: I only included those because I thought the problem might have been that there were trailing or preceding spaces. If I take them out, I get the same results. And yes, I have tried the <= and >= operators instead of BETWEEN